# Do today's modern compilers perform run time checks?

Tags: optimization, compiler, compilation, runtime

This is regarding compilers.

Do compilers perform run time dependency checks to decide to vectorize a loop ? In other words, do compilers trace through the logic as it would in run-time to determine if a loop can be vectorized?

Is it that when the compiler compiles a code and if auto-vectorization is enabled(default) then the output is a vectorized code targeted with lets say AVX assembly instructions then when did it perform the dependency checks ?

Comment: Isn't the point of the pragma to do the optimization without any testing? At least none done by compiler?

Comment: My question is not regarding pragma. My question is who performs run time data dependency checks ?

Comment: I guess whoever put that pragma in there.

Comment: tell me does the compiler do the run time checks if there is no #prgama directive ?

Comment: Your question explicitly states the compiler won't do any vectorization if it can't find the pragma. So no test is necessary. Or at least it will be much more careful in doing so.

Comment: I have reframed my question. it seems it was not clear from my question what i was asking ...sorry for that.

Comment: There is no language tag on this question: do you have a specific language or compiler in mind? Different language standards have different constraints and guarantees, and [different compilers have different levels of optimization](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/151375/22815).

Answer (score 5):

For a compiler to do run time checks (to find warnings and errors that cannot be found at compile time, including loop vectorization), it starts to get dangerously close to the [Halting Problem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

> Alan Turing proved in 1936 that a general algorithm to solve the halting problem for all possible program-input pairs **cannot exist**. A key part of the proof was a mathematical definition of a computer and program, which became known as a Turing machine; the halting problem is undecidable over Turing machines. It is one of the first examples of a decision problem.

Consider the following Java program:

```
public class Halting {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    while(isCondition()) {

    }
  }

  private static boolean isCondition() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

This program returns no errors or warnings by the compiler. It would have to trace through the logic to see that it is an infinite loop. What's to stop the theoretical run time checker from getting stuck in an infinite loop the same way? The compiler can't get stuck in an infinite loop, it's not *smart enough*.

Notice, on the other hand, that this does have an error:

```
public class Halting {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    String foo = null;
    System.out.println(foo.charAt(0));
  }
}
```

This yields the warning:

> Null pointer access: The variable foo can only be null at this location

Such checks are the best the compiler can do. But notice that this has no warning, even though it's the same problem:

```
public class Halting {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    String foo = getFoo();
    System.out.println(foo.charAt(0));
  }

  private static String getFoo() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: So if i have a for loop and the compiler vectorizes it, there is also a report generated saying loop was vectorized, does that mean it did it in compile time ? The reason I am asking is because Intel's document on auto-vectorization says the compiler perform run time checks and it is confusing me. Do they mean run time of the compiler(even the compiler takes some time to execute right !) or is there such a term ?     please check this link   https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/GUID-32ED933F-5E8A-4909-A581-4E9DB59A6933.htm

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any do, but it should be possible. For example [gcc 4.8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html) (scroll down to IA-32/x86-64 section) has both a builtin  __builtin_cpu_supports function and function multiversioning support  that the developer can use to write different code for different architectures. I don't see why the compiler couldn't generate different codepaths dependant on the runtime using these features automatically.

For example, manually:

```
__attribute__ ((target ("default")))
int foo(void)
{
  return 1;
}

__attribute__ ((target ("sse4.2")))
int foo(void)
{
  return 2;
}

int main (void)
{
  int (*p) = &foo;
  assert ((*p)() == foo());
  return 0;
}
```